# Calling location manager in a class

Tags: java, android, location, android-context

I have the following class

```
public class GPSManager  {


Context MyContext;
boolean GotLocation = false;
Location CurrentLocation;

public GPSManager(Context context){
    MyContext =  context;
}
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)MyContext.getSystemService(MyContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);


LocationListener locationlistener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        GotLocation = true;
      CurrentLocation = location;
    }
```

//etc

being called like below called from an activity

```
GPSManager myGPS = new GPSManager(this);
```

but when I run it fails I believe its something to with the context passing, as in the debugger I *think* (still new to Eclipse) its a null value.

All I want is a class that returns the current location (not necessary the last know location)

Comment: This doesn't look like a proper cut and paste - is all of that supposed to be in the GPSManager constructor?

Comment: GPSManager myGPS = new GPSManager(this); is called from an activity

Comment: Think Ive fixed it - codes running at least (but not doing what want :( )

Had the GPSmanager mygps.... line in the wrong place needed to be onCreate

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your Activity you can receive your current location, Add
`locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
locationListener = new CurrentGPSLocation();locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, locationListener);`
in your onCreate function.
 then add...
`private class CurrentGPSLocation implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint CurrentLocation = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
    }
}`